# I keep getting an out of bounds and I do not know why. Can someone help while still being able to follow the prompt for the lab? Must be done in java

Tags: java, arrays

For this lab, you will enter two numbers in base ten and translate them to binary. You will then add the numbers in binary and print out the result.
All numbers entered will be between 0 and 255, inclusive, and binary output is limited to 8 bits. 
This means that the sum of the two added numbers will also be limited to 8 bits. 
If the sum of the two numbers is more than 8 bits, please print the first 8 digits of the sum and the message "Error: overflow".
Your program should represent binary numbers using integer arrays, with the ones digit (2^0) stored at index 0, the twos digit (2^1) stored at index 1, all the way up to the 2^7 digit stored at index 7.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment_7{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a base ten number between 0 and 255, inclusive.");   
        int base1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a base ten number between 0 and 255, inclusive.");   
        int base2 = input.nextInt();

        int [] bi1 = convertToBinary(base1);
        int [] bi2 = convertToBinary(base2);

        System.out.println("First binary number:");
        printBin(bi1);

        System.out.println("Second binary number:");
        printBin(bi2);

        System.out.println("Added:");
        printBin(addBin(bi1,bi2));
    }


    //Adds the two binary numbers stored in the arrays, and returns the
 sum in a new array of ints.

    public static int[] addBin(int a[], int b[]){
        int carry = 0;
        int [] bi = new int [7];
        for (int i= 7;i>=0;i--){
            int sum = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
            bi[i] = sum %2;
            carry = sum/2;
        }
        if (carry==1){

          System.out.println("Error: overflow");
        }
       return bi;
    } 
    //Translates the parameter to a binary value and returns it stored as an array of ints.

    private static int[] convertToBinary(int b){
        int bin[] = new int[7];
        int bit = 0;
        while(b > 0){
            bin[bit++] = b%2;
            b = b/2;
        }
        int [] temp = new int[bit];
        for(int i = bit-1;i >= 0;i--){
            bin[i] = temp[i] ;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //Outputs the binary number stored in the array on one line. Please note, there should be exactly one space between each output 0 or 1

    private static void printBin(int b[]){
        for(int i =0;i < b.length;i++)
            System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is here

```
int [] bi = new int [7];
for (int i= 7;i>=0;i--){
```

since `bi` has a size of 7 the maximum index you can access is 6. I would recommend :

```
for (int i = bi.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

There is also a potential issue in `convertToBinary`. You are passing an `int` that could be 0-255. That requires 8 bits to represent. But :

```
int bin[] = new int[7];
```

Set the size of `bin` to 8 and ideally check that the number you pass is 0-255 before processing

Comment: I did and it did not seem to help

Comment: Wait I changed the new int [7] to [8] at int bin [ ]  and it worked thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

In your `addBin` method, change

```
for (int i = 7;i>=0;i--)
```

to

```
for (int i = 6;i>=0;i--)
```

You declare your array with a size of 7:

```
int [] bi = new int [7];
```

so the call to `bi[7]` is invalid *(0 based index)*; & you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thank you but, I am still getting an out of bounds for some reason

Comment: Can you spot exactly the error line ?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at Assignment_7.addBin(Assignment_7.java:41)
 at Assignment_7.main(Assignment_7.java:29)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Comment: sorry I am using dr.java which I am not used to. It is my first year with java and switching from only knowing python basics into an ap course with a new has been a little difficult

Comment: I think that you should change `int [] temp = new int[bit];` to `int [] temp = new int[7];` in your **convertToBinary** method.

Comment: I just tried and no dice

Comment: You're on your own now mate. Try adding `System.out.println` statements in your **addBin** method to figure out what goes wrong. Good luck.

Comment: I got it to work thank you fro your help

Comment: It is still wrong but it works

Comment: You will figure it out... you're welcome.